# How to make the same page show different results according to permissions in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have the following situation. In Drupal 8 I need to add a sub-page to the admin/content menu (ex. /admin/content/tasks), and make this page visible to specific admin role in the tabs menu, but not the admin/content page itself, or if I keep the page accesible to be able to completely hide the content of it. I've been looking for a solution for two days now and I still cannot find anything.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain more clearly about: "make this page visible to specific admin role in the tabs menu, but not the admin / content page itself, or if I keep the page accesible to be able to completely hide the content of it". It seems too confusing.

Comment: If I am with the role of SuperAdmin I should see all pages normally, but if I enter with the role, for example, TasksAdmin I should not be able to see the Content -> Overview page, but only the Content -> Tasks page. The problem is that if I don't give permissions for "Access content administration page" the entire tab is hidden from the menu with all of its sub-menus.

Comment: How did you create your `Tasks page`? Is it a view or custom page/form?